# Put ellipsis on react svg text component

Tags: javascript, svg, reactjs

I need your help because I have some troubles with the react's svg text component.
I'm trying to render text label with a fixed width. But i'm unable to find a way to put an ellipsis on the label if the text is too long.

```
var label = "Here is a really long text";
<text width={10}>{label}</text>
```

should render as

```
<text width={10}>Here is a really...</text>
```

What is the better way to resolve this issue? 
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it works with text label but try adding this style to text.

```js
let textSty = {
  overflow: 'hidden',
  textAlign: 'left',
  textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
  whiteSpace: 'nowrap'
}
```

Comment: Thanks Janaka, I tried your solution but unfortunately it seems that there is no style available for text element in order to obtain the expected result.

Comment: <text style={textSty}>

Comment: Hi janaka, sorry, what i meant in my previous sentence is that it seems that this style can not be applied on text element, because these properties are not available for text element